# Data driven framework on Selenium Grid 2

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid2

In my project we have decided to implement Selenium `Grid` setup.

We are using a data driven from `Excel` framework, currently all these spreadsheets are present in a workstation (which will turn to a hub once we implement `Grid`).

I was wondering after implementation of `Grid` once I run browser specific test run on the `nodes` (3 as of now) do I need to copy the spreadsheets containing data to all `nodes` ?

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it is using any online `code repository` like `GitHub` or `SVN` and then you can configure your CI tool like `Jenkins` to fetch the latest code which will include everything your sheets, your code e.t.c. and then it will run the test cases on `Selenium Grid`

You already know how to configure `Selenium Grid` just take a look at how to setup a CI tool.

If you aren't interested in setting up a CI tool, in this case you need to copy your entire code base and Excel sheets in the machine where Selenium Grid is running.